# Octave box legend not proper width with upper case text

Tags: plot, octave, legend, word-wrap, legend-properties

I'm reading data from files and use the file's names as legend, but Octave not proper render the originals file's names (in upper case).

This is my Octave script (with dummy plot data)

```
files = dir('*.ASC');
fileName = "";

figure
title ("lower case");
xlabel ("xdata");
ylabel ("ydata");

for i = 1:length(files(:,1))
  fileName = files(i,1).name;

  x = i*2
  plot(x, x + 5*x^2, 'DisplayName', lower(fileName));
  hold on;

endfor

h = legend ("location", "northeastoutside");
legend (h, "location", "northeastoutside");
set (h, "interpreter", "tex");
hold off;
grid on;


figure
title ("UPPER CASE");
xlabel ("xdata");
ylabel ("ydata");
for i = 1:length(files(:,1))
  fileName = files(i,1).name;

  x = i*2
  plot(x, x + 5*x^2, 'DisplayName', toupper(fileName));
  hold on;

endfor

h = legend ("location", "northeastoutside");
legend (h, "location", "northeastoutside");
set (h, "interpreter", "tex");
hold off;
grid on;
```

[image: lower case]
[image: UPPER CASE]

Comment: You can query / modify the properties of any graphical object (including legend boxes) using `get` and `set`.

Comment: btw, I cannot reproduce the problem. The defaults figure works fine on my setup. Perhaps you have a small monitor which limits the possible size of the figure. You could try forcing a large enough figure size to ensure there is enough space for the names in the legend box, etc.

Comment: I haven't found how to get or set legend's box width. How can I do it?

Comment: the box's width is determined by its 'position' property. E.g. try this: `LPos = get(h, 'position'); LPos += [-0.01, 0, 0.01, 0]; set(h, 'position', LPos);` to shift the box to the left by 1% (of the figure's width), and extend its width at the same time by the same amount.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't resize the legend box. I'm using Octave 5.2.0.

Comment: so am I. using your code. did you do something different?

Comment: the same three lines that you recommended me. Note that this doesn't happen when I convert to lower case, although the legend text be longer.

Comment: updated my answer below to confirm that this is a Octave/gnuplot bug even in version 6.2, and a bug report has been filed and confirmed as valid.

Answer (score 0):

running Octave 6.2.0 64bit on Windows 10, I don't get the same results you do.
From comments it looks like it's specific to certain graphics toolkits. Comparing all three, I can verify your results with the `gnuplot` toolkit.

I made a folder with three ASC files named filenamewithlargename1.ASC (and 2 and 3) and running your script copied exactly from what you posted above.

```
graphics_toolkit('qt')
```

[image: qt toolkit figures, no legend text issues]

```
graphics_toolkit('fltk')
```

[image: fltk toolkit figures, no legend text issues]

graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')

[image: gnuplot toolkit figures, showing the legend text size issue]

So it appears that the issue you've reported is specific to the gnuplot toolkit, and is still present in Octave 6.2.0.

this can be more simply demonstrated using the following code. it's not quite clear to me how the label box width is determined, and different text lengths do and don't reproduce the problem:

```
graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')    

plot([1 2 3],[4 5 6], 'DisplayName','thisisaverylongname');

legend

figure

plot([1 2 3],[4 5 6], 'DisplayName','THISISAVERYLONGNAME');

legend
```

which produces:

[image: simple gnuplot test showing label length problem]

I didn't see this in any particular label bug report, so I submitted this as [bug #60433](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?60433) on the Octave bug tracker.

It is also worth noting that for all toolkits, the plot commands clear the `title` and `label` settings you try to apply first.  This behavior is the same in Matlab, so isn't really a bug.  Recommend waiting to apply those annotations until after plotting is finished.

Comment: I note that your plot viewer is different from mine. Show in this image https://imgur.com/a/mpdKkHS

Comment: That's why I asked what graphics toolkit you're using.  Run the command `graphics_toolkit`. What does it say? . mine is the default qt toolkit. Other options could be gnuplot or fltk. You can change toolkit to see if the results change with, e.g., `graphics_toolkit('fltk')`

Comment: circling back to this, looking at your posted imgur image, the icon in the upper right corner of the figure window suggests you're running the gnuplot graphics_toolkit. I'll update my answer with a comparison.